# Xamarin Mobile App Dev Guide - How to load a local Web Site (HTML/CSS/JS ..) in a WebView for iOS, Android & UWP

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, webview, uwp

How to load and present a website like content, made of HTML, CSS, JS, Images ... from a local folder in iOS, Android & UWP Apps, using WebView (Xamarin Forms)

Answer (score 2):

This is quick guide to how load HTML files and its CSS, JS, Images .. from a local folder and present it with in Xamarin Page, using WebView.

**First Few General Notes:**

1. Using Xamarin you can develop apps for iOS, Android and Windows
   Universal Platform (UWP).
2. Xamarin default template, basically crates a project for each these 3 types of mobile apps and one master project. usual naming convention for these 4 project is:

   **ProjectName  (master)

   ProjectName.iOS

   ProjectName.Android

   ProjectName.UWP**
3. Folder structure in device base projects are matching the device type (iOS device, Androids and Win 10 based devices).

**Let's Get Started:**

1.You need to copy your entire website like folder (let's call it "WebRoot") to its correspondent place in each one of the device base projects:

- For Android copy WebRoot Under **"Assets"** (Set files "Build Action" to **AndroidAsset**)
- For iOS You can either copy it under project root folder or under **"Resources"** (Set files "Build Action" to **BundleResource** or **Content**)
- For UWP copy it just under the project root. (Set files "Build Action" to **Content**)

2. Best to Setup a Dependency to resolve and normalize URL Base for your WebRoot in each project (this will enable href(s) with relative url and so on)

- Add folder called Services to each device project, and add a C# class to each of them:

For Android Project (Services -> RootBaseUrl_Android.cs):

```
    using System.Text;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using ProjectName.Droid.Services;
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(RootBaseUrl_Android))]
    namespace ProjectName.Droid.Services
    {
        public class RootBaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
        {
            public string GetUrl()
            {
                return "file:///android_asset/";
            }
        }
    }
```

For iOS Project (Services -> RootBaseUrl_iOS.cs):

```
<pre>

    using Foundation;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using ProjectName.iOS.Services;
    
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(RootBaseUrl_iOS))]
    namespace ProjectName.iOS.Services
    {
        public class RootBaseUrl_iOS : IBaseUrl
        {
            public string GetUrl()
            {
                return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
            }
        }
    }

</pre>
```

For UWP Project (Services -> RootBaseUrl_UWP.cs):

```
<pre>

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using ProjectName.UWP.Services;
    
    
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(RootBaseUrl_UWP))]
    namespace ProjectName.UWP.Services
    {
        public class RootBaseUrl_UWP : IBaseUrl
        {
            public string GetUrl()
            {
                return "ms-appx-web:///";
            }
        }
    }

</pre>
```

And Finally Create Interface in Master Project (Services -> IBaseUrl.cs)

```
<pre>

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace ProjectName
    {
        public interface IBaseUrl
        {
            string GetUrl();
        }
    }

</pre>
```

3. Then setup a webview with such BaseUrl in Views (i.e: Views -> RootPage.xaml.cs):

   ```
         ...
         WebView rootWebView = new WebView();
         var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
         htmlSource.BaseUrl = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get().GetUrl(), "WebRoot/");
         htmlSource.Html = @" Write Your HTML STRING With href to Index.html of WebRoot IN HERE ";
         rootWebView.Source = htmlSource;
         rootWebView.WidthRequest = 800;
         rootWebView.HeightRequest = 1000;
         StackLayout.Children.Add(rootWebView);
         ...
   ```
4. Instead of writing a HTML STRING, you can do better by creating index.html or moving index.html from WebRoot Dir on each project to Master Project (Let's Call This Folder MasterWebRoot and Let's Put Our Index.html there!), You can reference it in your XamlPage using Assembly (.NET) :

   ```
       ...
       var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(RootPage)).Assembly;
       Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourProject.MasterWebRoot.index.html");
       String text = "";
       using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
             {
                 text = reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
       WebView rootWebView = new WebView();
       var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
       htmlSource.BaseUrl = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get().GetUrl(), "WebRoot/");
       htmlSource.Html = text;
       rootWebView.Source = htmlSource;
       rootWebView.WidthRequest = 800;
       rootWebView.HeightRequest = 1000;
       ...
   ```

This way you have a **common initial index.html** which resides in your master project (.Net) with all relative href(s) to the regarding copy of WebRoot (Your Local WebSite Folder) which resides on each device specific projects (Android, iOS & UWP).

**Note 1:** Don't forget to give a value to WidthRequest & HeightRequest of the WebView, otherwise you won't be able to see anything!

Hope it helps, Enjoy!

You Can Read More:
How Handle Files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Xamarin & WebView:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

**Note 2: Permissions:**
In order for WebView to work, you must make sure that permissions are set for each platform. Note that on some platforms, WebView will work in debug mode, but not when built for release. That is because some permissions, like those for internet access on Android, are set by default by Visual Studio for Mac when in debug mode.
**UWP** – requires the Internet (Client & Server) capability when displaying network content.
**Android** – requires INTERNET only when displaying content from the network. Local content requires no special permissions.
**iOS** – requires no special permissions.

**Note 3:** Be advised UWP is using:
Source file is on the web:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
```

Source file is in local storage:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView2" Source="ms-appdata:///local/intro/welcome.html"/>
```

Source file is in the app package:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView3" Source="ms-appx-web:///help/about.html"/>
```

Comment: OMG seriously Xamarin, can you not make this any easier??? SEIROUSSSLLL!YYYY!!!!!